# node publish state

Tags: 7

is there a simple way to control the node's publish state under a content type? eg: a content type "`test`", when the content is created by the admin, the article will be published. when the user iseditor, the article will be approved by admin that can publish. when i unchecked the box(published) which in the content type `test` `workflow settings`. both the admin and editor creating articles are can't be published

Answer (score 4):

As Berdir stated you could use the rules module to un/publish specific content depending to the role of the creator. 
You could also implement [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) in a module to get this done. The operation would be 'presave' and the code something like that:

```
YOURMODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
    if($op == 'presave' && $node->type == 'YOURTYPE') {
        global $user;
        if (in_array('YOURROLE', array_values($user->roles))) {
            $node->status = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I checked the contenttype and user role to upublish content. You can do all sort of things.

Comment: i am sorry, i have tested the above code, but it can't work. when i publish a story as role administrator. then i logout to see the page, it shows  i have no perssion to access the page, the articles status is unpublished.

Comment: The code requires the nodes to be published by default. It unpublishes them if the constraints (contentype + role) hit. You could do it the other way around (status = 1) if that fits your problem better (e.g. there are 10 roles which can't publish and only one is allowed to).

Comment: i changed the $node->status = 1; it still can't work. i want to the administrator role publish. the rest role unpublish.

Comment: Could you post your code? Can you debug (dsm() or print_r()) and check if the code inside the inner `if` is ever reached? Is the module not activated or are there any typos?

Comment: function alterform_nodeapi(&$node,$op,$a3=NULL,$a4=NULL){ if($op== 'presave' && $node->type == 'story'){ global $user;
if(in_array('administrator',array_values($user->roles))){ $node->status =1;}}}

Comment: i using echo 'test' on the if($op....), the page can output test. when i put the echo 'test' into the if body, the page can't output the test.when i delete the $op=='presave'， it can output the test

Answer (score 0):

If you change the default to don't publish, only users with the appropriate permission can change it, for all others, it will use the default.

You could then for example build a view with unpublished content, that you can go through and publish want you want. The default content list has a filter to show only unpublished content too, so that might work too.

Comment: i am sorry,the description of my question maybe unclearly. i want to when the admin creates the article that published. the editor can't.

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.org/project/rules then, that might help you.